# Putting multiple plots in a A4 sheet by using R codes

Tags: r, plot

I have 6 number of plots in R and I wanted to plot them in a single view. In other words , I want to put them in a single page in A4 size.

The plot code I am using is:

```
 plot(temp$ambtemp,type="o", pch=22, lty=2, col="brown",xlab = "Hour  2007/09/30" , ylab= "Tempreture" )

 title(main="Hourly Mean, node 25", col.main="brown", font.main=1)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a reproducible example of how you might do this:

```
pdf('eg.pdf', width = 8.3, height = 11.7)  ## Device with dimensions of A4 paper
par(omi = rep(.5, 4))                      ## 1/2 inch outer margins
par(mfrow = c(3,2))                        ## 2x3 grid of plotting areas
replicate(plot(rnorm(99)), n = 6)          ## 6 example plots
dev.off()
```

Comment: More precisely, re `width, height`: ...`mm=function(x)10*cm(x=1)`... `width=210/mm()`... `height=297/mm()`. Setting `paper="a4"` can also be used to set page size; this seems to have side effects imposing different length units for other measures (e.g., margins).  Reference: search "international paper sizes."

Answer (score 3):

The `layout` function allows you to partition a single device (e.g. an A4 papge) into several areas that you can use for plots.

Comment: And how I can put number of plots in a single layout.

Comment: You use the `layout` function to tell R how to partition the device. Then you simply call `plot` a corresponding number of times. Say you have a 2x2 layout. First call to `plot` will draw the graph in the top left corner. Subsequent calls will draw in all the other partitions up to a total of 4 plots after having called `plot` 4 times.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way if you use standard graphics is with  `par(mfrow=c(3,2))`. Nothing else needed. 
However, I strongly recommend having a look at `lattice` or `ggplot2` graphics if you want to make really nice multi-panel plot (which is also the answer to you last question).

Comment: +1 for lattice or ggplot2, although this only works if the plots are the same plots but for different levels of a factor in the data. For example, `a` vs `b` for every level of `c`. If the plots are totally different, facetting or lattice plots will not work optimally. Ofcourse, `ggplot2` and `lattice` have their own means of achieving the same result as `par(mfrow)`.